# Accepted and Unaccepted for the same answer

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I noted a strange thing in my reputation change. I have been awarded reputation for both an **Accepted** and **Unaccepted** for the same question. I don't understand this. An answer can either be **accepted** or **unaccepted** at a time, how can it be both. When I checked my answer on that particular question, it was only showing **accepted** with 0 Upvotes.

Here are my screenshots of both the reputation change and my answer on the question :

[image: My Reputation Change]

[image]

Comment: That user unaccepted your answer and immediately re-accepted it.

Comment: Finally since the answer remain accepted, then I should be awarded **+15** score for that

Comment: You have been award +15 the day before. The asker just unaccepted it somehow but re-accepted it 2 seconds later. Check the timestamp: [unaccept](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OELBZ.png), [accept](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tynkp.png).

Comment: Okk. I got it, thnx for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP had already accepted your answer *yesterday*. Today, they briefly accepted another answer (automatically unaccepting yours), then *re*-accepted your answer.

See the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24261552/timeline):

[image]

When you mouse over the timestamps, you'll see there are 2 seconds between the OP accepting the other answer, then going back to yours.

Perhaps they thought they could mark more than one answer as accepted, discovered they couldn't, and stuck to your answer.

The first accept got you +15 points. Unaccepting today, you lost those points again, then re-gained them. Your net result is +15.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination