# Accepted and Unaccepted at the same time

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

Today, I posted an answer to a question that was accepted:

[Unity C# TouchScript - Overlapped collider detection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408878/unity-c-sharp-touchscript-overlapped-collider-detection-issue/37411731#37411731)

However, when I look at my rep history, I see that the answer was first unaccepted, then accepted.

[image]

Looking at the timestamps when hovering on the history, I see that both accept and un-accept events occurred at the exact same second (maybe the user double clicked). However, looking at the post, the answer is still accepted. Looking at my history, it is not and I got no rep for it.

It this a bug or am I missing something ?

Note: this question [Accepted and Unaccepted for the same answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260990/accepted-and-unaccepted-for-the-same-answer) looks similar but the explanation was that an "accept" event occured the previous day. In my case there is no previous event on the post

Comment: Well, I don't see unaccept event in your reputation history.

Comment: oh, you are right, it was just updated! Apparently stackoverflow corrects that kind of display errors occasionally. took a few hours, I should have waited a bit before posting here

Comment: I did see it earlier. Weird how it caches that for a short time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my question after seeing the comment from Gothdo:

The display in my history has been updated.
Apparently Stack Overflow corrects that kind of display errors after a while. It took a few hours, I should have waited a bit before posting here.

Comment: The system does automatically fix oddities like this on its own through various recalculation scripts that run at different intervals. The user did accept your answer, then unaccept it a couple minutes later to instantly reaccept it (probably via a double click as you suggested).